# Dropwizard sundial library creates a new instance of scheduled object every time. Can we avoid it anyhow. Something like java timer

Tags: java, dropwizard, timertask

I was using sundial for job scheduling in my dropwizard project. I observed that every time it schedules a job, it create a new object of the scheduled task. Isn't it very poor design.
On other hand, java Timer that schedules the TimerTask, just creates the object once and invokes the run method on every schedule.

Comment: Why not use DW provided managed interface?

Comment: I'm not aware about it. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: I will post an alternative approach for your issue using the managed approach with dropwizad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so a way to solve your issue with DW is to used the managed approach. DW provides an interface called Managed that you can register with jetty. Jetty takes care of starting and stopping these and you have full control over execution of your tasks. Using a DI framework you can define your own execution rules.

Imagine the following class:

```
public class MessageTask implements Managed, Runnable {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MessageTask.class);

    private ScheduledExecutorService mainRunner = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setDaemon(true).setNameFormat("task-%d").build());

    // injected by DI or set programatically

    @Inject
    private long delay;

    @Inject
    private long period;


    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        mainRunner.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, delay, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        mainRunner.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            runInner();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error executing task", e);
        }
    }

    private void runInner() throws Exception {
        // do your timer task work here
    }

}
```

This is a Managed task. Registering it with DW will cause the framework to call the start and stop method when the server starts up or stops.

You define an executer (scheduled) within the class and implement it as a Runnable (no multiple object creation)

On start, you schedule your task with the configured delay and period you require.

On stop, you will shutdown your scheduler.

The threadpool is a deamon thread so it will not block shutdown of the JVM.

You need to catch the exception in the run method because the threadpool executor framework will otherwise silently drop the task after an exception.

The runInner() method will execute whatever logic you require.

Configuration can be done via a DI framework (I am using guicey which integrates guice and DW) or programatically, see: http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#managed-objects

This of course doesn't really answer your question - it is only an alternative solution. I have sadly never worked with your framework so I can not comment on it. But the above is a lightweight solution that does not require any other frameworks to be pulled into your application.

I hope that gives some inside.

Artur

Comment: Thats a neat way to do things. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: you could accept the answer if you think it is correct ;) With the same approach you could built your own framework to mimic the framework you were trying to use (e.g. use cron-like syntax to execute your queries)